# Scraping multiple posts from a web page

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to scrape every job on a page and I don't succeed. I kept trying different methods and I don't succeed. The script crashes after opening and scraping the first work. I don't know what I should do next to continue with the next jobs. Does anyone help me make it work? Thank you in advance.
I had to shorten the code because it didn't allow me to post it all (too much code).

```html
# Part 1
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
options = Options()    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Title","Description",'Job-type','Skills'])

for i in range(25):
    driver.get('https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/care-jobs?pageno='+ str(i))
    jobs = []
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)

    for job in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div[3]'):

        soup = BeautifulSoup(job.get_attribute('innerHTML'),'html.parser')
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
                     EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#onetrust-accept-btn-handler")))
        element.click()
        try:
            title = soup.find("h3",class_="title").text.replace("\n","").strip()
            print(title)
        except:
            title = 'None'

        sum_div = job.find_element_by_css_selector('#jobSection42826858 > div.row > div > header > h3 > a')

        sum_div.click()
    
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)
        try:            
            job_desc = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#content > div > div.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12 > article > div > div.branded-job-details--container > div.branded-job--content > div.branded-job--description-container > div').text
            #print(job_desc)
        except:
            job_desc = 'None'  

        try:
            job_type = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/article/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/span').text
            #print(job_type)
        except:
            job_type = 'None' 

        try:
            job_skills = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/article/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[6]/div[2]/ul').text
            #print(job_skills)
        except:
            job_skills = 'None'
        driver.back()
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)   

        df = df.append({'Title':title,"Description":job_desc,'Job-type':job_type,'Skills':job_skills},ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Desktop\Python\newreed.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: Why `driver.back()` ?  Is that really needed?  At quick glance seems redundant. Any debug info?

Comment: I just inserted the backup driver there to get me back to the main page, with or without the driver back is the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is trickier to manage with selenium than firefox or edge, in my opinion. If chrome is not required, then I would try and use the firefox or Edge driver. I have had luck with Edge when Chrome gave me issues.

Comment: I think the problem will be with any driver, the problem for me is that I don't know how to make selenium scrape my next posts.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using Selenium (which is not originally designed for web scraping). You should rather investigate F12 -> Network -> html or xhr tab.

Here is my code :

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def processPageData(soup):
    articles = soup.find_all("article")
    resultats = {}
    for article in articles:

        resultats[article["id"][10:]] = {}

        res1 = article.find_all("div", {"class", "metadata"})[0]
        location = res1.find("li", {"class", "location"}).text.strip().split('\n')
        resultats[article["id"][10:]]['location'] = list(map(str.strip, location))
        resultats[article["id"][10:]]['salary'] = res1.find("li", {"class", "salary"}).text

        resultats[article["id"][10:]]['description'] = article.find_all("div", {"class", "description"})[0].find("p").text

        resultats[article["id"][10:]]['posted_by'] = article.find_all("div", {"class", "posted-by"})[0].text.strip()
    
    return resultats
```

Iterate on the previous function :

```
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0",
           "Host": "www.reed.co.uk"}
            
resultats = {}

for i in range(1, 10):
    url = " https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/care-jobs?pageno=%d" % i

    s = rq.session()
    resp = s.get(url, headers=headers)#.text
    soup = bs(resp.text, "lxml")
    r = processPageData(soup)
    resultats.update(r)
```

gives :

```
{'42826858': {'location': ['Horsham', 'West Sussex'],
  'salary': '£11.50 - £14.20 per hour',
  'description': 'Come and join the team as a Care Assistant and make the Alina Homecare difference. We are looking for kind and caring people who want to make a difference to the lives of others. If you have a caring attitude and willingness to make a difference, come...',
  'posted_by': 'Posted Today by Alina Homecare'},

 '42827040': {'location': ['Redhill', 'Surrey'],
  'salary': '£11.00 - £13.00 per hour',
  'description': 'Come and join the team as a Care Assistant and make the Alina Homecare difference. We are looking for kind and caring people who want to make a difference to the lives of others. If you have a caring attitude and willingness to make a difference, come...',
  'posted_by': 'Posted Today by Alina Homecare'},

....
```

*Note 1:* the **resultats** keys are the identifiers allowing you to navigate to the job page if you need more details.

*Note 2:* I iterate on pages from 1 to 10; but you can try to adapt the code to have exactly the maximum number of pages.

*Note 3:* (as general recommendation) Try to understand the data model of the website rather than putting too much try except and using selenium in the wrong way.

*Note 4:* css selector and xpath selectors are ugly ; prefer cleaner selection by tag. (personal opinion)

Comment: I forgot the title. But you can easily add it.